# Удаление элементов из вложенных список

Tags: python, list

сталкнулся с тем, что есть необходимость удалять определенные элементы из отдельного подсписка главного списка. И казалось бы, в чем проблема, берем remove и полетели, но вся беда в том, что в подсписках списка элемнты могут совпадать и remove удалит и их. Что делать? Как удалить конкретный элемент подсписка главного списка, если он может быть и в других подсписках списка?

```
for i in range(len(text)):
        newMassiv = []
        for j in range(len(text)):
            newMassiv.append((random.choice(SubMassive[i])))                
            SubMassive[i].remove(newMassiv[j])
        massive.append(newMassiv)
```

Comment: Нужно нормально поставить задачу. Какие именно элементы нужно удалять? Пример не помешает.

Comment: Думал, хорошо описал
Суть такова
У нас есть некий текст, который разбивается в массив по символьно. Текст построен так, что пробелов нет. Считайте, что это набор символов, не более.
По этому набору создается список списков. Допустим, входной 12345 - текст
Тогда список списков будет - [[1,2,3,4,5][1,2,3,4,5] и так 5 раз]
Теперь задача переписать этот список так, чтобы элемент подсписка встречался только 1 раз, но в другом порядке
Допустим, так
[[2,1,4,5,3][5,3,1,2,4] и так до 5]

В целом суть в том, чтобы составить латинский квадрат, на данном же этапе

Comment: хочу сгенерировать рандомные последовательности

Comment: А причём тут удаление? Вы показываете перестановки [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: А это единственный способ, который я смог придумать. По поводу перестановок я даже не подумал.
Да и мне такой способ показался более удобным, чтобы рандомно генерировать

Comment: Да и в целом, мне придется же проверять конкретный элемент последовательности на повторение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько различных способов подойти к этой проблеме.

Лучшим подходом было бы использовать метод фильтра для создания нового списка, содержащего только те элементы, которые вы хотите сохранить. Затем вы можете использовать метод расширения, чтобы добавить отфильтрованный список в основной список. Это позволит вам избежать удаления любых элементов, которые также присутствуют в других подсписках.

Вот пример того, как этот подход мог бы работать:

```
# Создайте новый список, содержащий только те элементы, которые мы хотим сохранить
filtered_list = filter(lambda x: x not in SubMassive[i], text)

# Добавьте отфильтрованный список в основной список
massive.extend(filtered_list)
```

В качестве альтернативы вы могли бы использовать цикл for для перебора элементов в подсписке и использовать ключевое слово del для удаления каждого элемента из основного списка. Этот подход потенциально может вызвать проблемы, если один и тот же элемент появляется в нескольких подсписках, но он может быть более эффективным, чем использование метода фильтрации, если у вас есть только небольшое количество элементов для удаления.

Вот пример того, как этот подход мог бы работать:

```
# Используйте цикл for для перебора элементов в подсписке
for element in SubMassive[i]:
    # Используйте ключевое слово del, чтобы удалить каждый элемент из основного списка
    del text[element]

# Добавьте остальные элементы из основного списка в новый список
massive.extend(text)
```